# Boolean expression in If condition is not working in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to create a scenario in automation in which it enters Login credentials and clicks on Sign In button and after that it searches for an element. If element is displayed then it prints Valid Credentials and if element is not displayed then it does some other operation but code doesn't work after clicking on Sign In button.
Here I have created a method for it.

```java
public void toCheckLoginVerification() throws InterruptedException,MalformedURLException {
    clickOnSignInbutton();
    enterEmailId("s243535@yopmail.com");
    enterPassword("Test@123");
    clickOnSignInButtonOnSignInScreen(); //code not working after this.
    boolean x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Trips']")).isDisplayed();
    if(x==true) {
        System.out.println("Valid Credentials");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Credentials");
        clearEmailid();
        clearPassword();
        enterEmailId("s2@yopmail.com");
        enterPassword("Test@123");
        clickOnSignInButtonOnSignInScreen();
        clickOnProfileButtonOnHomeScreen();
    }
}
```

I have created the above methods in other class but calling them here.
To be more specific I am using Appium.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description. What is it supposed to do, based on what guaranteed input, what are you seeing it do instead, and what have you already done to debug the problem (e.g. looked up and verified the API calls you're making, putting breakpoints to inspect values, etc)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry if I couldn't describe my problem but this is all i know as of now.

Comment: Presumably you wrote this code, so: did you look up the Selenium API documentation for the functions you're calling? Do they say that the code you've written is the correct way to use them?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, i have checked it.

Comment: Then remember that this is not a general help forum, there are [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) that you are expected to have read, so please update your post to follow them: put the details in your post. That includes saying what you've already checked/verified/debugged/etc. That way the people you're asking for help won't end up just recommending you do things you already did, but never told them you already did.

Answer (score 1):

You should use explicit wait instead of implicit wait.
With your code selenium finds the element at the moment it is just created but still not fully loaded / rendered. So when your `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Trips']"))` returns the element it is still not displayed / visible.
While you should wait until the element is found visible.
So, you can use the following method:

```
public boolean waitForElementToBeVisible(String xpath, int delay) {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, delay);
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now you can say:

```
if(waitForElementToBeVisible("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Trips']",10)){
    System.out.println("Valid Credentials");
} else{
    System.out.println("Invalid Credentials");
    clearEmailid();
    clearPassword();
    enterEmailId("s2@yopmail.com");
    enterPassword("Test@123");
    clickOnSignInButtonOnSignInScreen();
    clickOnProfileButtonOnHomeScreen();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether the element is displayed immediately..
Instead you should use implicit or explicit wait mechanism of selenium

Comment: I am using implicit wait. So, i think wait isn't a problem here and also I am using invalid credential at the start. So, it should directly go to else statement.